# Проблема с выделением памяти С++. malloc

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, malloc

В программе стали происходит какие-то рандомные(там где в принципе упасть не может) падения. Вот один из крэшай меня интересует

```
#0  0x00007ffff54d4fcf in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff54d63fa in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff55189c8 in __malloc_assert () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff551b6f9 in _int_malloc () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff551cf34 in malloc () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff5dec0c8 in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x0000000002faebd5 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<unsigned int> >::allocate (this=0x5db527f0, __n=1) at /usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:104
#7  0x0000000002faeab0 in std::__cxx11::_List_base<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_get_node (this=0x5db527f0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:392
#8  0x000000000306d147 in std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_create_node<unsigned int const&> (this=0x5db527f0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:571
#9  0x000000000306d02c in std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_insert<unsigned int const&> (this=0x5db527f0, __position=0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:1763
#10 0x00000000033d4d9d in std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::emplace_back<unsigned int const&> (this=0x5db527f0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:1099
#11 0x00000000033d4bff in std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_initialize_dispatch<std::_List_const_iterator<unsigned int> > (this=0x5db527f0, __first=425, __last=3) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:1692
#12 0x0000000003651ce9 in std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::list (this=0x5db527f0, __x=std::__cxx11::list = {...}) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_list.h:657
#13 0x00000000043c424f in std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >::pair (this=0x5db527e8) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:127
#14 0x00000000043c429e in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >::construct<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > const&> (this=0x7fffffffcc2f, __p=0x5db527e8) at /usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:120
#15 0x00000000043c404d in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >::construct<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > const&> (__a=..., __p=0x5db527e8) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/alloc_traits.h:530
#16 0x00000000043c3836 in std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, false> > >::_M_allocate_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > const&> (this=0x7fffffffcda0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1955
#17 0x00000000043c2e09 in std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_Hashtable(std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> > const&)::{lambda(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, false> const*)#1}::operator()(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, false> const*) const () at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable.h:1116
#18 0x00000000043c39b6 in std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_assign<std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_assign(std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> > const&)::{lambda(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, false> const*)#1}>(std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> > const&, std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_assign(std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> > const&)::{lambda(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, false> const*)#1} const&) (this=0x7fffffffcda0, __ht=..., __node_gen=...) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable.h:974
#19 0x00000000043c2ef0 in std::_Hashtable<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_Hashtable (this=0x7fffffffcda0, __ht=...) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable.h:1114
#20 0x00000000043c2b91 in std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::hash<unsigned int>, std::equal_to<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, std::__cxx11::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >::unordered_map (this=0x7fffffffcda0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:172
```

Тут происходит копирование std::unordered_map

Вот он:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<uint32, std::list<uint32> > ContainerInfo;
```

Как видно у нас тут нету никак указателей, лишь обычный примитивы и список.

Срабатывает это **__malloc_assert**

Что это может значить? Проблема в памяти т.к. не может выделится?

**Компилятор:**

```
gcc-5 (Debian 5.4.1-11) 5.4.1 20170519
```

**Флаги сборки:**

```
-ggdb3 -O0 -m64 -march=native -pipe
```

**ОС:**

```
Debian 8
```

Comment: Проверял через valgrind memcheck. Ничего не обнаружено...

Comment: Когда происходят случайные падения в местах, где падений быть не может, значит у Вас в коде есть неопределённое поведение с вероятностью в 99%. Вполне вероятно, что UB вызвано гонками на каком-то разделяемом объекте. В любом случае, SO тут Вам вряд ли поможет. Вам нужна трассировка, отладчик и много времени.

Comment: Ну т.е. получается что где то сломался хип и сейчас вообще совершенно другой код пытается взять памяти и падает из-за этого?

Comment: @user_21: Да, но это именно хип вашей программы и разрушен он был именно вашей программой. Т.е. код-то может быть и "соврешенно другой", но в любом случае это код вашей программы.

Comment: а может это оно https://habrahabr.ru/post/332552/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Где-то выше/раньше по коду в вашей программе была нарушена целостность внутренних структур heap. Об этом и говорит вам `malloc_assert`. Падение происходит на первой попытке выделения памяти, которая натыкается на это разрушение. Это происходит дальше/позже по коду, обычно в совершенно не относящемся к проблеме месте.

"Дедовским" методом отлова источника данной проблемы является следующий:

1. Посмотреть сколько памяти пытается выделить данный вызов `malloc`.
2. В своем коде непосредственно перед "падающим" обращением к вашему `unordered_map` вставить фиктивный вызов `malloc(...)` с точно таким же размером в качестве аргумента.
3. Убедиться, что теперь падает именно он.
4. Постепенно поднимать данный фиктивный вызов `malloc` вверх по коду, пока не обнаружится точное место, которое разрушает heap.

Применение этого способа - не всегда тривиальная задача. Надо обеспечить, чтобы фиктивный вызов `malloc` происходил только перед именно "падающим" обращением к `unordered_map`, т.е. на том же вызове функции, на той же итерации цикла и т.п. Но всего этого, при желании, можно достичь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Что вы подразумеваете по разрушением хипа?

Comment: @user_21: "Невидимые" служебные структуры, отвечающие за поддержание функциональности хипа. Например, во многих реализациях освобожденные блоки памяти ("дырки") хранят в себе служебные данные: свой размер и указатель на следующий свободный блок в списке свободных. Если кто-то вдруг запишет что-то в ранее освобожденный блок, эти служебные данные будут уничтожены. После этого запросто можно наткнуться на именно такое падение.

Comment: valgrind такое должен находить? Приложение большое и ручками проверять займёт о-очень много времени...

Comment: @user_21: По идее - должен.

Comment: @user_21, такие вещи хорошо искать санитайзерами из clang.

Comment: Что это такое? Можете дать ссылки посмотреть?

Comment: @user_21, посмотрите на [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) и гуглите по «clang sanitizer» если другие заинтересуют.

Comment: круто, а скажите куда он выводит инфу эту? Или он сразу убивает приложение?

Comment: @user_21, убивает сразу.

Comment: Большое спасибо нашёл этой тулзой проблему... Был доступ за границы статического массива....